# React using fetch returns undefined until save

Tags: reactjs, api, chart.js

new to react so I am not quite sure what I am doing wrong here... I am trying to call data from an API, then use this data to populate a charts.js based component. When I cmd + s, the API data is called in the console, but if I refresh I get 'Undefined'.

I know I am missing some key understanding about the useEffect hook here, but i just cant figure it out? All I want is to be able to access the array data in my component, so I can push the required values to an array... ive commented out my attempt at the for loop too..

Any advice would be greatly appreciated! My not so functional code below:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import {Pie} from 'react-chartjs-2'


const Piegraph = () => {

    const [chartData, setChartData] = useState();
    const [apiValue, setApiValue] = useState();

    useEffect(async() => {
        const response = await fetch('https://api.spacexdata.com/v4/launches/past');
        const data = await response.json();
        const item = data.results;
        setApiValue(item);
       chart();
    },[]);

   
    const chart = () => {

        console.log(apiValue);

        const success = [];
        const failure = [];
    
        // for(var i = 0; i < apiValue.length; i++){
        //     if(apiValue[i].success === true){
        //         success.push("success");
        //     } else if (apiValue[i].success === false){
        //         failure.push("failure");
        //     }
        // }
    
        var chartSuccess = success.length;
        var chartFail = failure.length;


        setChartData({
            labels: ['Success', 'Fail'],
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: 'Space X Launch Statistics', 
                    data: [chartSuccess, chartFail],
                    backgroundColor: ['rgba(75,192,192,0.6)'],
                    borderWidth: 4
                }
            ]
        })
    }

    

    return (
      <div className="chart_item" >
        <Pie data={chartData}  />
      </div>
    );
  }
  
  export default Piegraph;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple issues that need sorting out here. First, you can't pass an `async` function directly to the `useEffect` hook. Instead, define the async function *inside* the hook's callback and call it immediately.

Next, `chartData` is entirely derived from the `apiCall`, so you can make that derived rather than being its own state variable.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Pie } from "react-chartjs-2";

const Piegraph = () => {
  const [apiValue, setApiValue] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function loadData() {
      const response = await fetch(
        "https://api.spacexdata.com/v4/launches/past"
      );
      const data = await response.json();
      const item = data.results;
      setApiValue(item);
    }
    loadData();
  }, []);

  const success = apiValue.filter((v) => v.success);
  const failure = apiValue.filter((v) => !v.success);

  const chartSuccess = success.length;
  const chartFail = failure.length;

  const chartData = {
    labels: ["Success", "Fail"],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "Space X Launch Statistics",
        data: [chartSuccess, chartFail],
        backgroundColor: ["rgba(75,192,192,0.6)"],
        borderWidth: 4,
      },
    ],
  };

  return (
    <div className="chart_item">
      <Pie data={chartData} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Piegraph;
```

Comment: Thank you, this does work for me! I needed to remove results from data.results to get the filter method to work! Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 0):

pull your chart algorithm outside or send item in. Like this

```
  useEffect(async() => {
    ...
    // everything is good here
    chart(item)
  })
```

you might wonder why I need to send it in. Because inside useEffect, your apiValue isn't updated to the new value yet.

And if you put the console.log outside of `chart()`.

```
  console.log(apiData)
  const chart = () => {
  }
```

you'll get the value to be latest :) amazing ?

A quick explanation is that, the `Piegraph` is called whenever a state is updated. But this update happens a bit late in the next cycle. So the value won't be latest within `useEffect`.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help, iv'e implemented your changes which has solved the one issue (now I do see apiData in the console)... however, i now have two problems. 1) Im getting 4 x  array returns in the console and 2) if I try use my for loop i get "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"